# Curl command is not processing changes I make to file

Tags: node.js, curl, forever

I am trying to test parsing of a zip file in node.js using curl from the command line. Originally, I had a route that looks like this:

```
app.post('/processZip', (req, res) => {
const zip = req.file
console.log(req)
extractCSVFilesFromZip(zip, '/tmp/connections', '/tmp/messages')
const connectionsOutputPath = '/tmp/connections'
const messagesOutputPath = '/tmp/messages'
console.log(`Size of Parsed Connections File: ${connectionsOutputPath.size}`)
console.log(`Size of Parsed Messages File: ${messagesOutputPath.size}`)
res.send('success!')
})
```

which calls a function that looks like this:

```
const extractCSVFilesFromZip = (zipFilePath, connectionsCSVOutputPath, 
messagesCSVOutputPath) => {
console.log(zipFilePath)
fs.createReadStream(zipFilePath)
    .pipe(unzip.Parse())
    .on('entry', entry => {
        const [
            fileName,
            size
        ] = [
            entry.path,
            entry.size
        ]
        if (fileName === 'Connections.csv') {
            console.log(`Size of Connections File to Parse: ${size}`)
            entry.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(connectionsCSVOutputPath))
        } else if (fileName === 'Messages.csv') {
            console.log(`Size of Messages File to Parse: ${size}`)
            entry.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(messagesCSVOutputPath))
        } else {
            entry.autodrain()
        }
    })
   }
```

I am using this curl command to test the request:

curl -F file=@../../../Downloads/Basic_LinkedInDataExport_09-14-2018.zip http://localhost:5000/processZip/

Originally, it gave me an error pointing to the first instance of createReadStream in the function, so I commented out all the code and just tried to console.log(zipFilePath) to see what is being sent. But I still get the same error. In fact, I can comment out, remove, or change any of the code in either the route or the file, but it makes no difference. I still get the same error. It's as if curl is still sending the request to a cached version of the files, and not processing the changes I am making. But if I examine the files from the command line with sudo nano  I can see the updated versions. What could be causing this issue? I have saved the files and restarted the server each time. Could it be that I need to wait longer than usual for the changes to be processed because it is a larger codebase than I am used to working in, or is something else to blame. For what it is worth, the servers are being run by forever. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out, there was a ghost process running on 5000. killall -9 node did the trick!